# How do I correctly use the mouseleave function in my code?

Tags: javascript

Okay so I need to create a div with a red background that then registers the "Mouseleave" event which will then call a function that will display the following text "MouseLeave event fired". My goal is that when I move my mouse over my div and then move it away I will get an alert that says "MouseLeave event fired". Then when I click on my div again it will unregister the MouseLeave event that way when I move my mouse over the div nothing will happen. Here is my code I have so far:

```js
function attachEvent(myObject) {

     // to do - get state of listener 
     myObject.addEventListener("onmouseleave", function attachEvent(){}, false);
     alert("Mouse");

     // to do - if previously called addEventListener, then I now want to call removeEventListener
     myObject.removeEventListener("onmouseleave", function attachEvent(){}, false);
      
     // to do - if previously called removeEventListener, then I now want to call addEventListener 
     myObject.addEventListener("onmouseleave", function attachEvent(){}, false);
}
```

```css
div {background-color:red;padding:100px;max-width:25%;margin:auto}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>practice</title>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
       alert("Page loaded event fired");
  </script>
  <div id="cycle"; onclick="attachEvent(this)">
        <h2 style="text-align:center">Click to cycle event listener</h2>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I move my mouse out of the div the alert should pop up, but it's not. What am I doing wrong? Please keep the code like this for now as I'm not familiar with the getelementbyid yet.

Comment: you must also use mouseenter listener for mouseleave to work

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I need it so when I click on the div box it activates the listener which will show mouse for now and when I move my cursor out of the div I should get another alert saying mouseleave event fired.

Comment: @Akshaypadwal where it is documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You are not passing `this` correctly, `this` in your case is a global context.
- for `removeEventListener` to work, callback function can not be a anonymous function.
- Keep a flag to check whether you should add event or remove event. This flag will toggle its value on each click.
- Use `mouseleave` instead of `onmouseleave`, later one is used when event you are attaching is inline to the element.

```js
var eventExists = false;

function mouseLeft() {
  console.log("Mouse left!");
}

function attachEvent() {
  if (!eventExists) {
    this.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeft);
  } else {
    this.removeEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeft);
  }
  eventExists = !eventExists;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red;padding:10px" ; id="cycle" ; onclick="attachEvent.call(this)">
  <h2 style="text-align:center">Click to cycle event listener</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is exactly doing what OP want. This should be the accepted answer. up-vote for the details and snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much I've spent the past 9 hours trying to figure this damn thing out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of the event is `mouseleave`. `onmouseleave` is used when you set the event via HTML attributes (like you do with `onclick`).

I suggest you to define a function (`onMouseLeave` in my code below) and use it as parameter of `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Finally, you don't need to set the `useCapture` parameter to `false` (for both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`) because `false` is the default value.

```js
var eventAttached = false;

function attachEvent(myObject) {

    if(eventAttached === false){
      myObject.addEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseLeave);
    } else {
      myObject.removeEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseLeave);
    } 
    
    eventAttached = !eventAttached;
}

function onMouseLeave(){
  alert("Mouse leave");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>practice</title>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
       alert("Page loaded event fired");
  </script>
  <div style="background-color:red;padding:100px"; id="cycle"; onclick="attachEvent(this)">
        <h2 style="text-align:center">Click to cycle event listener</h2>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is the [type of the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) to listen to.

There is no `onmouseenter` event. `onmouseevent` is the internal name of the property that stores the event handler you install. The name of the event is `mouseenter`.

Your code should read:

```
myObject.addEventListener("mouseleave", function attachEvent(){}, false);
```

But the event handler you install using this code doesn't do anything; you won't be able to know when it is invoked. For testing you should add a call to `console.log()` inside the handler:

```
myObject.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){ console.log('Mouse is out of the house.'); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more easy using jquery:

```
$(myObject).mouseleave(function(){alert('MouseLeave event fired')});
```